# Accessing ConfigurationManager.AppSettings in Java script

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I had this javascript code in aspx file

Page.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Head" runat="server">
 ----some code----
 added after suggestion from Satpal
 <script type="text/javascript">
var GAAccountId = '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GAAccountId"]%>';
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<%--<script type="text/javascript">
        debugger;
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GAAccountId"]%>']);
        _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'auto']);
        _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/Register']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageLoadTime']);

        (function () {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();

    </script>--%>
</asp:Content>
```

Now I  moved this code to seprate .js file and included the reference in javascript file.Now I am not able to access it.it is coming as it `"'<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GAAccountId"]%>']"`

How to get the value from it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GAAccountId"]%>` will work when you are using it in `aspx` file. It will not be evaluated when you are using it in external js file.

You can do decalre a variable in aspx page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var GAAccountId = '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GAAccountId"]%>';
</script>
```

Use `GAAccountId` variable in JS File

Comment: Any suggestion how to get value from it in java script file

Comment: Global means within <asp:Content ID="Content2" ..is it ? or in the page it self.I tried putting in Content2 it not accesible in java script.

Comment: Where do i put this golabl variable in aspx file

Comment: @Chris_vr, golabl variable in head section aspx file

Comment: No Not working.When I print that in console it says undefined.I have updated the question