# DataTables - How to avoid hardcoding url?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

In my DataTables, I want to avoid repetition and keep the base address in web.config file. Then, I just need to concatenate the variable part.  Here's what I've done without success and the message from browser (IE 11):

> "DataTables warning: table id=configurationTable - Ajax error..."

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var url = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseAddress"])) + "Configuration";
        $('#configurationTable').DataTable({
            ajax: {
                'url': "'" + url + "'", //url is concatenated correctly
                'dataSrc': 'value',
            },...edited for brevity
```

Config setting:

```
<add key="BaseAddress" value="http://myServer:8083/api/"/>
```

Update:
I also have tried this without putting ***url*** in quotes.  Chrome show a 406 error - Not Acceptable

Update 2:
The Web API service I'm calling has OdataControllers and ApiControllers.  The prefixes for both are the same, so the OData ones need to be configured first in the WebApiConfig.  Plus, no quotes on the url argument.

Comment: What error are you getting? (follow this to get the error code/description: http://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7)

Comment: Try to change it  to `'url': url,`. There is no need to add single quotes.

Comment: @AlexArt...In Chrome it shows a 406 - Not Acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not wrap URL in single quotes.

Also I'm not ASP.NET expert, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18490546/3549014) your code should be changed to:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = '<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseAddress"] %>' + 'Configuration';
    $('#configurationTable').DataTable({
        ajax: {
           'url': url,
           'dataSrc': 'value'
        },
        // ... skipped ...
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this too, and no luck - same error.  It's a 406 - Not Acceptable

Comment: @BigDaddy, there could be some other issue unrelated to URL that is causing it. As long as you see request made to the correct URL, it means that solution with `<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseAddress"] %>` works.

Comment: You're right.  My routing was bad on the OData service I'm calling

Answer (score 0):

As you're using MVC, I'm assuming your js files are separate, ie not included in the View. If this is the case then accessing the value using `Razor` syntax won't work.

Try this:

In the model that you send to the View, add a property for the web.config setting:

```
public string BaseAddress
{
    get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseAddress"]; }
}
```

This way, when you pass the model to the view, it always has the `BaseAddress` value. in the View you add a hidden field:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.BaseAddress, new { id = "baseaddress" })
```

And your datatables initialisation js code can retrieve it:

```
url: $("#baseaddress").val() + '/Configuration';
```

Comment: Thanks, please see my Update 2 comment.