# Passing values from web.config through an .aspx page to an external JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, function

I have a JavaScript function that I wrote and embedded in an .aspx page. I declared variables at the top of the function that access ConfigurationManager.AppSettings and also the sessionState tag as follows:

```
var Value1 = "<%= System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Value1"].ToString()%>";
var Value2 = "<%= Session.Timeout %>";
```

This function has been working just fine. I've realized that I will need to use the function across four other pages so I decided to move it to an external JavaScript file. According to this question and accepted answer...

[Accessing ConfigurationManager.AppSettings in Java script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490503/accessing-configurationmanager-appsettings-in-java-script)

...external JavaScript files do not evaluate code inside of these "server-side code" tags, therefore, values from the web.config file must be passed from the .aspx page as parameters. I moved the function to an external JavaScript file and call the function like this:

```
<script src="Scripts/JavaScript.js" type="text/javascript">    
    var Value1 = "<%= System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Value1"].ToString()%>";
    var Value2 = "<%= Session.Timeout %>";
    externalFunction(Value1, Value2)
</script>
```

The external JavaScript functions begins as follows:

```
function externalFunction(Value1_, Value2_) {
    debugger;

    var Value1 = Value_1;
    var Value2 = Value_2;

...

}
```

As I debug the JavaScript function, the arguments themselves are undefined. What am I missing here?

### Update - 4/12/17

I have tried calling the function in both of the following ways.

```
<script src="Scripts/JavaScript.js" type="text/javascript">        
    var Value1 = "1";
    var Value2 = "2";        
    externalFunction(Value1, Value2);
</script>

<script src="Scripts/JavaScript.js" type="text/javascript">        
    var Value1 = "1";
    var Value2 = "2";        
</script>
<script src="Scripts/JavaScript.js" type="text/javascript">        
    externalFunction(Value1, Value2);
</script>
```

Using IE's debugger, I can see that the values were pulled correctly from the web.config file, but the function still is not being called. I'm stumped.

Comment: I think you need to include the vars in a separate script tag before your external script is included (never seen anyone actually put script inside and external script so not sure if that works) - like this: https://jsfiddle.net/cc45w6nr/1

Comment: Do I still need to indicate that externalFunction() requires two arguments in the external JavaScript file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with two separate script tags, and see any different.

```
<script src="Scripts/JavaScript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Value1 = "<%= System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Value1"].ToString()%>";
    var Value2 = "<%= Session.Timeout %>";      
    externalFunction(Value1, Value2);
</script>
```

Comment: You cannot load external script file, and run JavaScript code in same script tag.

Comment: Okay, asked and answered. Thank you very much.